# Prove that any real symmetrical matrix is guaranteed to have an eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My question is a prerequisite for [If two eigenvectors share eigenvalues, why is there no unique decomposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172975/if-two-eigenvectors-share-eigenvalues-why-is-there-no-unique-decomposition)

How would I prove that:

> While any real symmetric matrix A is guaranteed to have an
>   eigendecomposition, the eigendecomposition may not be unique.

I understand why it may not be unique, but what property guarantees that there is at least one eigendecomposition?

If this statement is equal to *"characteristic polynomial of every real symmetrical matrix has a at least one real root"*, then my question, again, is what property guarantees that?

Comment: The statement is *stronger* than the one you gave. For example, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has only real eigenvalues, but does not have an eigendecomposition (it is not diagonalisable).

Comment: In other words for eigendecomposition to be possible the number of eigenvalues should be equal to the rank of matrix?

Comment: No, the dimensions of all the eigenspaces need to add up to the size of the matrix.

Comment: Isn’t the number of eigenspaces equal to the number of distinct eigenvalues?